# IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService failed w/ kIOReturnNoResources/0xe00002be

Tags: macos, iokit

**IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService** failed w/ kIOReturnNoResources/0xe00002be

I am rewriting old FireWire based command line utility into XPCService. I need some help about an IOKit function.

- Following part is to get IOCFPlugInInterface for FireWireAVCLibUnit.
  (almost same as original code; basic idea comes from legacy simpleAVC samplecode).
- When I call `IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService()` in the XPCService, it always failed returning `0xe00002be = kIOReturnNoResources` in IOReturn.h.
- I have confirmed no sandbox, no hardened for the XPC Service.
- Original command line utility works perfectly on macOS 10.14 though, would you someone give me a hint on this topic?

---

```
CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, self.dict);
kern_return_t result = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, dict, &serviceIterator);
if (result == KERN_SUCCESS && serviceIterator != IO_OBJECT_NULL) {
    while ((service = IOIteratorNext(serviceIterator)) != IO_OBJECT_NULL) {
        SInt32 score = 0;
        kern_return_t result = IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService(service,
                                                                 kIOFireWireAVCLibUnitTypeID,
                                                                 kIOCFPlugInInterfaceID,
                                                                 &interface,
                                                                 &score);
        if (result != KERN_SUCCESS) continue;
        // result 0xe00002be = kIOReturnNoResources in IOReturn.h
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**Additional details**

I have find IOCFPlugIn.c in opensource.apple.com. After basic verification, 
- `IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService()` failed to `IOCFPlugIn->Start()` .

```
(*iunknown)->QueryInterface(iunknown, CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(interfaceType),
                    (LPVOID *)&interface);
<snip>
kr = (*interface)->Probe(interface, plist, service, &score);
<snip>
haveOne = (kIOReturnSuccess == (*interface)->Start(interface, plist, service));
```

- Probe() returned kIOReturnSuccess though,
- Start() failed w/ kIOReturnNoDevice = 0xe00002c0. and haveOne = false.
- Finally IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService() returned kIOReturnNoResources = 0xe00002be.

Is this related to some security feature on macOS?

---

**MODIFIED**

- I have found hardened runtime with Camera access was rejected FireWireAVCLibUnit (tccd shows error).
- Even if no sandbox, no hardened for the XPC Service in Xcode was checked, XPCservice is handled via sandbox. (macOS 10.14.6 + Xcode 10.3)
- I would appreciate if you have an advice.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution.
- Add NSCameraUsageDescription in Info.plist, and IOFireWireAVCUserClient will work.
- If sandboxed, com.apple.security.device.firewire is also required.

---

Even if capabilities-sandbox is off, tccd verify info.plist.
If “Privacy - Camera Usage Description” is not available, sandboxd reject to use IOFireWireAVCUserClient device.

[Information Property List Key Reference/Cocoa Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Add com.apple.security.device.usb : YES to plist resolve this issue.